# Using auto-layout to make a perfect square

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have a view with an imageview in it. I'd like to be able to make it so that the imageview always remains a perfect square, but I am not entirely sure how to implement this with autolayout.

My screen looks like so currently:

[image]

The imageview is what I'd like to be square, no matter the width dimension. I understand that this may be able to be done with constraints, and I have tried, but ultimately have been unable to figure out how to achieve this. This is perhaps due to my relative inexperience with autolayout, storyboards and ios development in general

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should set 4 constraints for your square view: `Top Spacing`, `Leading Spaces`, `Trailing Spaces` and `Aspect Ratio`. This is shown bellow:[image]

Make sure that the aspect ratio of your square is 1:1
[image]

Hope this helps and good luck with Auto Layout!

Comment: this works in protrait, but when the device rotates to landscape how can the size be handled properly?

Answer (score 1):

There is an aspect ratio constraint. You can set that to 1:1

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IB: in the storyboard, control-drag from the image view to itself. You'll be able to set an Aspect Ratio constraint and set its value ("multiplier") to 1:1. Of course you'll need to set the width or height somehow too.

From code, just add another constraint so the view's width is equal to the view's height.